# how to set progressbar while downloading file from ftp

Tags: c#, vb.net, download

following code is used to download an exe file from driveHq

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim strFTPpath, strDestPath As String
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        'strFTPpath is the url of where Latest upd is located
        'strDestPath is system path to dwonload upd from FTP
        strFTPpath = "ftp://MYUSRNAM:MYPWD@ftp.drivehq.com/rstari9kremcos/RStari9.exe"
        strDestPath = "D:\Rstari9\GDS\RStari9.exe"
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(strFTPpath, strDestPath)
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow
        Button1.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("latest updation successfully downloaded to 'D:\Rstari9\GDS\RStari9.exe'", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "RStari9 - Download Success")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update downloading aborted...")
    End Try
End Sub
```

and [this is my UI to download](http://imageshack.com/a/img850/8918/4dgs.jpg), i want to add a progressbar in it

code : `VB.NET`

Comment: Don't do it in UI thread or it'll stop your UI until finished. Use a BackgroundWorker. With DownloadFile() you won't get notifications about downloading status so you can't show a progress bar (unless you just want a marquee). What you may do is to set showUi parameter to true.

Comment: @Adriano any example ??

Comment: Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229675(v=vs.90).aspx), it's not exactly what you're doing but it'll explain technique.

Answer (score 0):

[My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) has a parameter called `showUI`, you can set it to True to *display the progress of the operation*.
You can change your code in this way:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(strFTPpath, strDestPath, "", "", True, 100000, False)
```

Unfortunately, My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile hasn't a way to download the file asynchronously, so you have to use something else if you want to develop your own UI.